# Return a value in c# function

Tags: c#, asp.net, return-value

I have a function in .CS file. i want to return many values fetched in the function to .aspx.cs file(both files in the same project)

How to return a values from the below function(.CS file code is as follows):

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;


using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Data
/// </summary>
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //



    }
    public void dat(AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor Editor1,TextBox TextBox3, TextBox TextBox4, TextBox TextBox2, TextBox TextBox1, DropDownList DropDownList1, DropDownList DropDownList3, HiddenField HiddenField1, HiddenField HiddenField4)
{    
    String dbDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");

        String respo1 = "";
        String respo2 = "";
        String editorcont1 = "";
        int res = 0;
        String sb = "";

        String petitioner = "";
        String petitioner1 = "";
        String resp = "";
        String resp1 = "";

        String respondants = "";
        String addr1 = "";
        String addr2 = "";


        var order = "";

        String nextdate = "";
        String nextdate1 = "**/**/****";
        String judge1 = "";
        String judge2 = "";
        String judge3 = "";
        String advocates = "";


        String a = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
        String b = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value.PadLeft(3, '0');
        String c = TextBox1.Text.PadLeft(5, '0').ToString();
        String d = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
        String digit = a + b + c + d;
        String jjj = "";


        try
        {
            OdbcConnection casetype = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=10.155.160.130;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=;Option=3;");
            casetype.Open();

            String petresquery1 = "select fil_no from testcase.main where reg_no =? OR fil_no=?";
            OdbcCommand petrescmd1 = new OdbcCommand(petresquery1, casetype);
            petrescmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", digit);
            petrescmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", digit);
            OdbcDataReader respetMyReader1 = petrescmd1.ExecuteReader();

            while (respetMyReader1.Read())
            {
                String fil_no = respetMyReader1["fil_no"].ToString();
                HiddenField4.Value = fil_no;
                //Response.Write(HiddenField4.Value);
            }


            string showmodifquery = "select notice from notice_aspx where fil_no=?";

            OdbcCommand showmodifcmd = new OdbcCommand(showmodifquery, casetype);

            showmodifcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
            OdbcDataReader showmodifMyReader = showmodifcmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (showmodifMyReader.Read())
            {
                String showmodif1 = showmodifMyReader["notice"].ToString();

               Editor1.Content = showmodif1;
            }
            else
            {
                //************to get case type     
                string casetypequery = "select casename from casetype where skey=?";
                //************to get pet  res
                string petresquery = "select pet_name,res_name from testcase.main where reg_no =? OR fil_no=?";
                //*******to get respondants 
                string respoquery = "SELECT sr_no,partyname,addr1,addr2 FROM testcase.party where fil_no=? and pet_res='R'order by sr_no,party_lh,party_lh2,party_lh3,party_lh4,party_lh5";
                //*******to get order
                string ordequery = "select orde from testcase.orddetpabak where fil_no=? and orderdate=?";
                //*********to get next date
                string nextdatequery = "SELECT next_dt FROM testcase.heardt where fil_no=? and next_dt>?;";
                //*********to get jud1
                string jud1query = "select jname from testcase.orddetpabak,testcase.judge where orddetpabak.jud1 = judge.jcode and fil_no=? and orderdate=?;";
                //*********to get jud2
                string jud2query = "select jname from testcase.orddetpabak,testcase.judge where orddetpabak.jud2 = judge.jcode and fil_no=? and orderdate=?;";
                //*********to get jud3
                string jud3query = "select jname from testcase.orddetpabak,testcase.judge where orddetpabak.jud3 = judge.jcode and fil_no=? and orderdate=?;";
                //*********to get advocates
                string advquery = "SELECT adv FROM testcase.orddetpabak where fil_no=? and orderdate=?";



                //************to get case type 
                OdbcCommand casetypecmd = new OdbcCommand(casetypequery, casetype);
                String casetypefromdropdown = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.ToString();
                casetypecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", casetypefromdropdown);
                using (OdbcDataReader casetypeMyReader = casetypecmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (casetypeMyReader.Read())
                    {
                        String casename = casetypeMyReader["casename"].ToString();
                        HiddenField1.Value = casename;
                    }
                }

                //************to get pet  res
                OdbcCommand petrescmd = new OdbcCommand(petresquery, casetype);
                petrescmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", digit);
                petrescmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", digit);
                using (OdbcDataReader respetMyReader = petrescmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (respetMyReader.Read())
                    {
                        petitioner1 = respetMyReader["pet_name"].ToString();

                        //petitioner1 = petitioner.Substring(0, 1) + petitioner.Substring(1).ToLower();
                        resp1 = respetMyReader["res_name"].ToString();
                        //resp1 = resp.Substring(0, 1) + resp.Substring(1).ToLower();

                        //String fil_no = respetMyReader["fil_no"].ToString();
                        //HiddenField4.Value = fil_no;
                        ////Response.Write(HiddenField4.Value);
                      // return petitioner1;
                    }
                    if (petitioner1 == "")
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<b><font color='red'>Wrong Entry!!!");
                    }
                }


                //*******to get respondants

                String respo = HiddenField4.Value;
                OdbcCommand respocmd = new OdbcCommand(respoquery, casetype);
                respocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", respo);
                using (OdbcDataReader respoMyReader = respocmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (respoMyReader.Read())
                    {
                        respo1 = respoMyReader["sr_no"].ToString();
                        respo2 = respoMyReader["partyname"].ToString();
                        addr1 = respoMyReader["addr1"].ToString();
                        addr2 = respoMyReader["addr2"].ToString();
                        res = Convert.ToInt32(respo1);
                        //Response.Write(res);
                        //Response.Write(respo2);

                        //editorcont1 = "<table><tr><td width='10'>" + res + "</td><td>"+"<P align= 'left'>"+  respo2 +"</P></td>"+"</br>";

                        ////HiddenField7.Value = editorcont1;
                        //asd(editorcont1);

                        //respondants = respo2.Substring(0, 1) + respo2.Substring(1).ToLower();
                        //addr1 = addr1.Substring(0, 1) + addr1.Substring(1).ToLower();
                        //addr2 = addr2.Substring(0, 1) + addr2.Substring(1).ToLower();
                        editorcont1 = res + ")&nbsp;&nbsp;" + respo2 + "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + addr1 + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + addr2 + "<br/>";
                        sb = sb + editorcont1;
                    }
                }

                //*******to get order
                OdbcCommand ordecmd = new OdbcCommand(ordequery, casetype);
                ordecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
                ordecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dbDate);
                using (OdbcDataReader ordeMyReader = ordecmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (ordeMyReader.Read())
                    {
                        order = ordeMyReader["orde"].ToString();
                    }

                }
                //*******to get nextdate
                OdbcCommand nextdatecmd = new OdbcCommand(nextdatequery, casetype);
                nextdatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
                nextdatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dbDate);
                using (OdbcDataReader nextdateMyReader = nextdatecmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (nextdateMyReader.Read())
                    {
                        nextdate = nextdateMyReader["next_dt"].ToString();

                    }
                    nextdate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(nextdate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");


                }

                //*********to get jud1
                OdbcCommand jud1cmd = new OdbcCommand(jud1query, casetype);
                jud1cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
                jud1cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dbDate);
                using (OdbcDataReader jud1MyReader = jud1cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (jud1MyReader.Read())
                    {
                        judge1 = jud1MyReader["jname"].ToString();
                        jjj = "J";
                    }
                }


                //*********to get jud2
                OdbcCommand jud2cmd = new OdbcCommand(jud2query, casetype);
                jud2cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
                jud2cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dbDate);
                using (OdbcDataReader jud2MyReader = jud2cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (jud2MyReader.Read())
                    {
                        judge2 = jud2MyReader["jname"].ToString();
                        jjj = "JJ";
                    }
                }


                //*********to get jud3
                OdbcCommand jud3cmd = new OdbcCommand(jud3query, casetype);
                jud3cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
                jud3cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dbDate);
                using (OdbcDataReader jud3MyReader = jud3cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (jud3MyReader.Read())
                    {
                        judge3 = jud3MyReader["jname"].ToString();
                        jjj = "JJJ";
                    }
                }
                //*******to get advocates
                OdbcCommand advcmd = new OdbcCommand(advquery, casetype);
                advcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
                advcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dbDate);
                using (OdbcDataReader advMyReader = advcmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (advMyReader.Read())
                    {
                        advocates = advMyReader["adv"].ToString();
                    }

                }
                DateTime month = DateTime.Now;
                String tyear = TextBox2.Text;
                tyear = tyear.Remove(0, 2);

                String year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                year = year.Remove(0, 2);

                TextBox4.Text = order;
            }
        }
                    catch (Exception er)
        { }

}
}
```

I want to pass advocates,jjj,tyear,year,petitioner1,resp1,sb etc... How can i do it??

Comment: Not related but just an advice: don't just catch errors and do nothing with it... this way you will never know what went wrong when something is not working. Either do something with the exception (e.g. log into database) or don't catch it at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encapsulate all of the related values in a new type, and make your method return an instance of that type.

Oh, and try to avoid having such *huge* methods - they're a nightmare for readability, testing etc.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to return more than one value from a method, you need to create a class to do so.

For example:

```
public class Product
{
   int Id { get; set;} 
   string Name { get; set;} 
   double Value { get; set;}
}
```

And then when you want to return a Product from your method:

```
public Product GetProduct(string Id) 
{
   Product product; 
   // load product here
   return product; 
}
```

Comment: You could also use a struct to return small pieces of data. They might result in a better performance.

Comment: Performance for constructing a class vs creating a struct? Overall savings probably less time than it'd take to explain what a struct is :)

Comment: Actually when you take into account the get/set on that class you'd be saving quite a lot of time (esp if you had calls to the method in a nested loop)

Answer (score 1):

Functions only return one value.  Use "out" or "ref" parameters for multiple return values.

See here:  http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html