# Problem using return() in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, return-value

```
    string casetype6(HiddenField HiddenField1,DropDownList DropDownList3)
        {
            String casetype1="";

            try
            {
                OdbcConnection casetype = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=10.155.160.130;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=;Option=3;");
                casetype.Open();

                //************to get case type    
                string casetypequery = "select casename from casetype where skey=?";

                //************to get case type
                OdbcCommand casetypecmd = new OdbcCommand(casetypequery, casetype);
                String casetypefromdropdown = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.ToString();
                casetypecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", casetypefromdropdown);
                using (OdbcDataReader casetypeMyReader = casetypecmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (casetypeMyReader.Read())
                    {
                        String casename = casetypeMyReader["casename"].ToString();
                        HiddenField1.Value = casename;
                        casetype1=HiddenField1.Value.ToString();
return casetype1;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ep)
            { }
        }
```

I want to use **casetype1** outside this method. How can i do it? 
If i say return casetype1 then error comes as:

```
    'Data.casetype6(System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)': not all code paths return a value
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return a value in c# function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613984/return-a-value-in-c-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `return casetype1;` after ending braces of catch section.

Answer (score 3):

Your method doesn't return anything if somehow you don't enter the `while loop` (in case your `casetypeMyReader` is empty) or some exception is thrown (connection failed to database). Following is changed code. Have a look.

```
string casetype6(HiddenField HiddenField1,DropDownList DropDownList3)
{
    String casetype1="";

    try
    {
        OdbcConnection casetype = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=10.155.160.130;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=;Option=3;");
        casetype.Open();

        //************to get case type    
        string casetypequery = "select casename from casetype where skey=?";

        //************to get case type
        OdbcCommand casetypecmd = new OdbcCommand(casetypequery, casetype);
        String casetypefromdropdown = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.ToString();
        casetypecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", casetypefromdropdown);
        using (OdbcDataReader casetypeMyReader = casetypecmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (casetypeMyReader.Read())
            {
                String casename = casetypeMyReader["casename"].ToString();
                HiddenField1.Value = casename;
                casetype1 = HiddenField1.Value.ToString();
                break; // instead of returning from here, break the loop
            }
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ep)
    { }

    return casetype1; // and return here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like return `string.Empty`, or **preferably do something** with the exception in your `catch` block.

There is always debate on where to put the `return`, be it at the end of the method, or at the point where you want to return. I personally like to return where the value can be returned, and then deal with the other problems where they need to be dealt with - in this instance, the catch block.