# problem using return() for multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, return-value

I am calling a function as:

```
string judge1 = abs.getjud1(this.HiddenField4, this.TextBox3);
```

The function being called is:

```
public string getjud1(HiddenField HiddenField4, TextBox TextBox3)
{
    String dbDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");

    try
    {
        OdbcConnection casetype = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=10.155.160.130;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=;Option=3;");
        casetype.Open();

        //*********to get jud1
        string jud1query = "select jname from testcase.orddetpabak,testcase.judge where orddetpabak.jud1 = judge.jcode and fil_no=? and orderdate=?;";

        //*********to get jud1
        OdbcCommand jud1cmd = new OdbcCommand(jud1query, casetype);
        jud1cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
        jud1cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dbDate);
        using (OdbcDataReader jud1MyReader = jud1cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (jud1MyReader.Read())
            {

                judge1 = jud1MyReader["jname"].ToString();
                Globals.jjj1= "J";
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ep)
    { }

    return judge1;
}
```

I want to return **judge1** and **Globals.jjj1**, is it possible to do that? If so than how to do it?

Comment: Globals.jj1 is a global object? If so why do you need to return it? Just query it when you need its value

Comment: How about looking at the answers from the similar question you asked yesterday?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return a value in c# function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613984/return-a-value-in-c-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean, but if you want to return multiple values, you can use the `out` or `ref` keywords.

[Out keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Ref keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    int value1;
    int value2;
    value1 = SomeOtherFunction(out value2);
    //Value1 now equals 21, value2 equals 25.
    //You can use the same thing for strings.
}

int SomeOtherFunction(out int value2)
{
    value2 = 25;
    return 21;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a Tuple

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with the 2 string values that represent the values you want and then return the object.

```
public MyCustomObject getjud1(HiddenField HiddenField4, TextBox TextBox3)
```

Comment: why bother creating our own types when we have Tuples for cases exactly like this :)

Comment: True, but I actually did not even know about their existence until 12 minutes ago after I read your answer :) Still think it you might get nicer code if its an object that will be reused a lot..

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one object from your method, but you have two options here:

1. Make a new object that contains two strings, and return this object from the method instead of the string. This way, your composite object will contain the values you want.
2. Make a new parameter that you mark as `out`, and set the value of that parameter inside the method. The variable you send into the method as a parameter will then be updated outside the method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# is an object oriented language, why not simply make an object that contains all the values that you want to return?  That way you only have one variable for your return statement, but you have access to all the values that you require.